# Kubuntu 14.04 - Network Manager shows only 3 VPN Op

Tags: networking, kubuntu, kde, vpn

This appears to be a new issue as I do not see records of it having startpage-d this particular issue.  I recently installed Kubuntu 14.04 on a new machine.  I did not observe the same problem with the network-manager in Ubuntu 12.04 or Debian 7.5/gnome, thus believe this pertains to Kubuntu/KDE specifically.

The network manager only shows a maximum of 3 "available" VPN connections under my wireless connection, whereas I have imported a couple of dozen.  They are accessible and configured if I click "Edit" but that does not allow me to connect any of the ones that are not displayed by clicking on the network manager in the GUI.

Unless someone has a fix, this may be a bug that needs to be reported to Kubuntu, KDE, or the maintainers of the network-manager.  I will ask first and then make the report as required.

UPDATED: placing he mouse over the corner of the box allows resizing. Not at the bottom.  Was then able to resize. Scrolling still appears not to work, which is maybe not an optimal design, but it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by placing he mouse over the corner of the GUI box that appears when clicking on the network manager.  Only the corner in KDE apparently allows resizing, not at the bottom. Scrolling also still appears not to work, which is maybe not an optimal design.  However, this problem is avoided by using the corner of the network manager window to resize it to see remaining OVPN options.